# No-message listener for handler

Tags: android, handler

I know, that Handler class has several methods for receiving messages. But I need some listener, which will notify me, when no message is sent to handler.

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: Method A must be called continuosly, and I want to know when it is NOT called. So I use a thread to check this. 
Everytime the A is called, it sends a message to handler, which means that the A is called and everything okay. 
Once the message is not sent means the A is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as "NOT called".

There is only "NOT called in a particular period of time".

For that, use `postDelayed()` with your `Handler`. When you receive a message, `removeCallbacks()` to get rid of any previous `postDelayed()` call, then call `postDelayed()` with a `Runnable`, and your desired timeout period. If your `Runnable` is invoked, you know that the timeout passed without having received a message.